# How to retrieve a date in a more human readable form

Tags: java, calendar

Whan I retrieve saved dataes from the database, I get something like:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1401785940000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/Los_Angeles",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/Los_Angeles,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2014,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=23,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=154,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=0,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=1,MINUTE=59,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-28800000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

How can I get a more human readable form, like `10.22.2014`?

Comment: Why you saved dates to database this way?

Comment: Which Java? Java 8? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) Else Calendar or DateFormatter (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DateFormatter.html)

Comment: You are printing the `GregorianCalendar` object. Use a formatter and format your date.

Comment: Hi @Masud. I'm saving via JFXtras. Thanks for the reply. Any ideas on how to approach it: that is best way to save. This is my first interaction with dates.

Comment: @ILikeProgramming, This is `toString()` method output of `GregorianCalendar`. You should save the data as `Date` format. You can get the `Date` from calendar using `getTime()` method before save to database.

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the Database. It should be `date` or `timestamp` instead of `varchar`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a `DateFormat`:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd.yyyy").format(calendar.getTime());
```